# Router management in CI 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need router management in my project.

My url is some thing like it.

> http://localhost/cloud/index.php/dashboard/view_tickets/wsyZCMuIEavPeWdRHqjJ

Here i want to replace "dashboard/view_tickets" as one word "tickets"

but i have tried using routers, its not working.

Router code:

```
$route['ticket/(:num)'] = 'Ticket/view_tickets/$1';
```

Here $1 is for num, but here my parameter has string only.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Well,if your example url is correct then :num would never match as you don't use numbers in that url try using (:any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$route['ticket/(:num)'] = 'Ticket/view_tickets/$1';
```

To this:

```
$route['ticket/(:any)'] = 'Ticket/view_tickets/$1';
```

To make it work, you should create a function called "view_tickets" under "Ticket" class (Controller).

Also please [see here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) to understand routing in Codeigniter.

Comment: Probably you didn't create correct Controller Class. Can you add your Controller's (Ticket.php) related parts here?